# how to set a firebase database rules by orderByChild

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to get all the score children by using a query

```java
orderByChild("namaGroup").equalTo(namaGroup)
```

in table `Results`
then I get the error permission denied

```
    W/SyncTree: Listen at /test123 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
    W/SyncTree: Listen at /Ulangan 1 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

here my database structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2765.png)

and my rules right now look like this

```
    "Results" : {
      ".indexOn":["namaGroup"],
        ".read": "true",
          ".write": "auth !=null",
```

the error appear on every child. I'm so confused to set a security rules :(

Comment: Your rules still may not work as you want (namaGroup is nested lower than Results and I'm not sure how that will work) but ```".read": "true",``` should not have quotes around ```true```.

Comment: i've solved my problem by using a logic code, thank for your response